# Updating a value in an array based on an argument

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

Using JavaScript or Jquery I have the below array that is sorted based on Start Date (coordinates):

```
[{
  elem: '<div id="task7">',
  startDate: 864,
  endDate: 999,
  order: 0
},
{
  elem: '<div id="task6">',
  startDate: 918,
  endDate: 1053,
  order: 1
},
{
  elem: '<div id="task5">',
  startDate: 945,
  endDate: 1269,
  order: 2
},
{
  elem: '<div id="task4">',
  startDate: 972,
  endDate: 1107,
  order: 3
},
{
  elem: '<div id="task8">',
  startDate: 1026,
  endDate: 1161,
  order: 4
}]
```

If a "startDate" of one string is greater than the "endDate" of any other string, I'd like to update the "order" value to the compared string where the argument is true.

Below is an example of what I'm trying to output where the "order" of string 4 is 0 (same as string 0):

```
[{
  elem: '<div id="task7">',
  startDate: 864,
  endDate: 999,
  order: 0
},
{
  elem: '<div id="task6">',
  startDate: 918,
  endDate: 1053,
  order: 1
},
{
  elem: '<div id="task5">',
  startDate: 945,
  endDate: 1269,
  order: 2
},
{
  elem: '<div id="task4">',
  startDate: 972,
  endDate: 1107,
  order: 3
},
{
  elem: '<div id="task8">',
  startDate: 1026,
  endDate: 1161,
  order: 0
}]
```

Comment: what if the `startDate` is greater than multiple `endDate` ? Should it use the first or the last `order` that was compared ?

Comment: Also, have you tried anything ?

Comment: If there are multiple endDate is should use the first order. I've spent the past day trying to find a solve - going through various sorting techniques via the web. Even a suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps

```js
var arr = [
  {elem: '<div id="task7">', startDate: 864, endDate: 999, order: 0},
  {elem: '<div id="task6">', startDate: 918, endDate: 1053, order: 1},
  {elem: '<div id="task5">', startDate: 945, endDate: 1269, order: 2},
  {elem: '<div id="task4">', startDate: 972, endDate: 1107, order: 3},
  {elem: '<div id="task8">', startDate: 1026, endDate: 1161, order: 4}
  ];


arr.forEach( function(start){
  var less = arr.filter(function(item){ return start.startDate > item.endDate})[0];
  
  if (less) start.order = less.order;
} );

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Yes! This gets me going in the direction I needed! Thank you!